# Ethereum Market Place Design

Tags: contract-design

I want to model the following scenario - a small market place
I have 2 nodes in my network - the seller and the buyer.
I want to model the market place in that why  - that the buyer node asks every seller node for their offer - the buyer node decided (based on some rules) which offer he will accept.

My questions is regarding the "asking each buyer node" for their offer. How does the smart contract of the buyer knows whom he should contact in the network? I want to avoid to hard code the adresses in the Smart Contract :-)

Thx

Comment: Without modelling the contract, you can create structs or contracts for each _order_ which includes addresses of buyers, sellers, escrowers, or whatever you like. You do not need to hardcode anything, just prepare the desired structure.